# select dropdown too large (Bootstrap)

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, input, dropdown

Ok, so i have a simple thing on my website where users can enter a phone number and text them, so when they enter the phone number they need to select an item in a dropdown list with all country dial codes, the problem is that the dropdown list is as long as my textbox which makes everything look quite awkward, I've done some research and have messed around with it myself without any luck, just for an example here is what i am talking about (btw i use the bootstrap framework so any answer would need to support bootstrap)
[image]

As you can see the text box is actually smaller than the dropdown list which makes it look kinda weird, i would like to somehow scale down the dropdown so it looks better along side my text field.

Thanks for reading, any help will be appreciated!

EDIT:
My current code for this `<select>` dropdown looks like this

```
<select class='form-control'>
    <option value='213'>Algeria (+213)</option>
    <option value='376'>Andorra (+376)</option>
    <option value='244'>Angola (+244)</option>
    <option value='1264'>Anguilla (+1264)</option>
    <option value='1268'>Antigua &amp; Barbuda (+1268)</option>
    <option value='54'>Argentina (+54)</option>
    <option value='374'>Armenia (+374)</option>
    <option value='297'>Aruba (+297)</option>
    <option value='61'>Australia (+61)</option>
//There is more countries..... I just cut it here so it won't be too long
</select>
```

Comment: Could you please show some code.

Comment: That **combo box** (not dropdown) doesn't really look like its a bootstrap component.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you just want to set a max width on that select element or its container.

Comment: Is there really a need to post all that code?

Comment: @CharlieFish I suppose not.. It's just an example of what I'm doing i guess

Comment: @coddding http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: do you need to reduce the width?? can you attach expected screenshot

Comment: What's wrong with `select {width:100px;}` ?

Comment: @CharlieFish Ok? I posted it to just show what my code looks like.... Not exactly sure why you wasted time posting that.... but ok i guess

Comment: @coddding It's clearly in the Stack Overflow guidelines to only include the code required to reproduce the issue. There are many reasons for that. I would edit your question and remove a large chunk of that and mention there are many more rows that are basically the same. There is like 0 reason to post all of that code. A fraction would suffice.